# How to reword this question to make it non-opinionated?

Tags: discussion

Here: [unity game engine - should I be using a di framework / ioc container](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/151304/unity-game-engine-should-i-be-using-a-di-framework-ioc-container)

I would love to get some information on this topic too. May someone give their opinions on how to reword this question so that it fits the Q&A format?

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see, the question hasn't yet attracted any close votes. It looks too broad to me, but not so much so that I'd want to close it unilaterally. So it might be a non-issue.

Then again, it also hasn't attracted any answers yet either. So edits that focus it on a more answerable scope might help encourage more contributions.

**As a general rule, I think "which technology should I use / should I implement solution Y" questions fit the Q&A format better when reframed as "How do I solve [problem X](http://xyproblem.info/)?"**

That gives us a clearer criterion to evaluate potential answers: "does it solve problem X?" as opposed to the more nebulous "does it demonstrate that technology Y 'should' or 'should not' be used in general?"

If the user describes a specific problem in their game, to which a dependency injection framework is an effective solution, then recommending that framework and detailing its benefits could be a correct answer.

This framing also leaves room for "actually, there's a simpler method to solve this particular problem" which we can't directly address if the question is "use dependency injection frameworks: yes or no?"